# Не считывается последний символ строки из файла

Tags: c++, строки, динамические-массивы, символы

Всем доброго времени суток. Задача для понимания смысла программы: напишите программный код для подсчёта числа цифр в данном файле и их суммы.
Как показала отладка, проблема заключается лишь в строчке fin.getline(str, N);. Она считывает всю строку кроме последнего символа в этой строке, соответственно в массив записывается вся строка посимвольно кроме последнего символа. Следовательно если при пользовательском вводе последним символом окажется цифра, то она не учтется при подсчете потому что ее попросту не будет в массиве.
Вопрос - каким образом/методом заставить программу считывать последний символ строки и записывать ее в массив?

Код прилагается:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

/*  Динамический массив нужен для записи в него строки из файла посимвольно
    при последующем его открытии. */

    int N;
    char *str = new char[N];

    int sum = 0;
    int num = 0;
    string s;

    ofstream fout("file.txt");
    cout << "Введите строку: " << endl;
    getline(cin, s);
    fout << s;
    N = s.size();

    fout.close();

    ifstream fin("file.txt");
    if (!fin)
    {
        cerr << "Ошибка." << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        while(fin)
            fin.getline(str, N); // на этом месте пропадает последний символ

        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            if((str[i] >= '0') && (str[i] <= '9'))
            {
                sum += str[i] - '0';
                num++;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "Сумма цифр = " << sum << endl;
    cout << "Кол-во цифр = " << num << endl;
    fin.close();

    delete [] str;

    getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Заранее спасибо за ответ. Критика приветствуется.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

После этого

```
int N;
char *str = new char[N];
```

нет никакого смысла говорить о любых дальнейших действиях в программе. Выделили непонятно сколько памяти, и хотите работать...

Эта фигня встречается уже не первый раз - тут что, тоже какой-то препод постарался? Считать, что если потом изменится N, то это автоматом приведет к изменению количества выделенной памяти?

Почему бы, кстати, если уж вы пишете строку `string` - не читать в такую же строку? `getline(fin,s)`? По крайней мере не пришлось бы с памятью напрямую возиться...

А последний символ пропадает, потому что вы сказали, что размер буфера для чтения - `N`, вот он и читает `N-1` символ, а потом нулевой дописывает - строка все же. И об этом ясно написано в описании этой функции - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline

Comment: Как раз и думал на нулевой символ, который ставится поверх последнего символа строки, чтобы не выходить за рамки буфера N.
Спасибо за совет с чтением в ту же строку, это действительно более практичный вариант.
Массив я использовал для того, чтобы лучше освоить аспекты работы с динамической памятью и проверить себя в этой теме. Видимо, все же надо доучивать матчасть.